# solaris + run script every night one time from the crontab

Tags: linux, solaris, cron

I build in my Solaris machine new script

Script name:  send_brd_msg.sh ( this script located under /var directory

I want to activate this script every 12:00 at night by the crontab

Please advice what to write in my crontab in order to run the /var/send_brd_msg.sh every night at 12:00 hour

my crontab:

```
  crontab -l
  #ident  "@(#)root       1.21    04/03/23 SMI"
  #
  # The root crontab should be used to perform accounting data collection.
  #
  #
  10 3 * * * /usr/sbin/logdm
  15 3 * * 0 /usr/lib/fs/nfs/nfrind
  30 3 * * * [ -x /usr/lib/gs/gred_clean ] && /usr/lib/gs/gin_clean
```

Answer (score 0):

12:00 at night is 00:00 on the 24 hour clock.

So, you would add a line like:

```
0 0 * * * /var/send_brd_msg.sh
```

to your crontab.